# How to validate if the input Username and Password is empty in ajax when submitting the form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is the Javascript. How do I validate if the input box is empty and console if error. Can Javascript alone validate it without PHP Query?

```js
$('#manage-user').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    start_load()
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax?action=save_user',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (resp) {
            if (resp == 1) {
                alert_toast("Data successfully saved", 'success')
                setTimeout(function () {
                    location.reload()
                }, 100)
            }
        }
    })
})
```

This is the form:

```html
<form action="" id="manage-user">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo isset($meta['id']) ? $meta['id']: '' ?>">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($meta['name']) ? $meta['name']: '' ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($meta['username']) ? $meta['username']: '' ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($meta['password']) ? $meta['password']: '' ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="type">User Type</label>
        <select name="type" id="type" class="custom-select">
            <option value="1" <?php echo isset($meta['type']) && $meta['type'] == 1 ? 'selected': '' ?>>Admin</option>
            <option value="2" <?php echo isset($meta['type']) && $meta['type'] == 2 ? 'selected': '' ?>>Cashier</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Never trust client side validation code, when you use the variables on the server. Only use client side validation to notify the user

Comment: Sure it’s possible, https://api.jquery.com/val/ gets you the current field values, so you can easily write some conditions to check what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all user inputs can't be trusted. So, I don't recommend you doing Client-Side Validation alone.

Now to do the validation on the client-side just get the current value from the Input Box and check if the value is empty or not.

```
const name=document.getElementById("name");
const username=document.getElementById("username");
const password=document.getElementById("password");
if(name!=""&&username!=""&&password!="")
{
alert("Perfect");
}
else
{
alert("All Fields are required");
}
```

You can use the code to check the inputs and send ajax request based on the result